# TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile_image_url' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

I have the following object and trying to access its properties.

However I am getting the error.

Here's my code:

```
export default class TweetsList extends Component {
state={
    tweet:''
}
componentDidMount(){
    var tweet_id  = window.location.search.split("id=")[1];
    console.log(tweet_id, 'tweet id');
    axios.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:4444/fetchSingleTweet', 
        data:{
            tweet_id: tweet_id,
            token: localStorage.getItem('token')
        },
    }).then((res)=>{  
        this.setState({tweet:res.data});     
    }).catch((err)=>{
        this.setState({isLoading:false});
    });
}
render(){
    let tweet = this.state.tweet;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(tweet.user))
    return(
      <div class="card">
            
          </div>
      )
}
```

}

I can access `tweet.user` but not `tweet.user.id` or any of `user` properties inside `render` function.

I consoled the object and it looks like:

```
{
created_at: "Tue Oct 02 09:06:45 +0000 2018", id: 1047050242053627900, 

id_str: "1047050242053627904", text: "RT @CharlesPPierce: When Worlds Collide.↵Over the …I learned that the guy who cut Brett Kavanaugh f…", truncated: false, …}

created_at: "Tue Oct 02 09:06:45 +0000 2018"
entities: {hashtags: Array(0), symbols: Array(0), user_mentions: Array(1), urls: Array(0)}
favorite_count: 0
favorited: true
geo: null
id: 1047050242053627900
id_str: "1047050242053627904"
in_reply_to_screen_name: null
in_reply_to_status_id: null
in_reply_to_status_id_str: null
in_reply_to_user_id: null
in_reply_to_user_id_str: null
is_quote_status: false
lang: "en"
place: null
retweet_count: 28
retweeted: false
retweeted_status: {created_at: "Mon Oct 01 12:19:08 +0000 2018", id: 1046736268418256900, id_str: "1046736268418256896", text: "When Worlds Collide.↵Over the weekend, thanks to Y…uy who cut Brett Kavanau…", truncated: true, …}
source: "<a href="" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPad</a>"
text: "RT @CharlesPPierce: When Worlds Collide.↵Over the weekend, thanks to Yahoo!'s Pete Thamel, I learned that the guy who cut Brett Kavanaugh f…"
truncated: false
user: {id: 938841256507183100, id_str: "938841256507183105", name: "Irene Kenneth", screen_name: "IreneKenneth3", location: "", …}
__proto__: Object
```

Also, here's the expanded view of `user` property:

```
    {
  "id": 736476636015530000,
  "id_str": "736476636015529987",
  "name": "NepalaYak",
  "screen_name": "NepalaYak",
  "location": "Kathmandu, Nepal",
  "description": "Treks & Tours Company. Let's discover #Nepal with #Nepalayak",
  "url": "some_url",
  "entities": {
    "url": {
      "urls": [
        {
          "url": "some_urlr",
          "expanded_url": "http://nepalayak.com/",
          "display_url": "nepalayak.com",
          "indices": [
            0,
            23
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "description": {
      "urls": []
    }
  },
  "protected": false,
  "followers_count": 198,
  "friends_count": 95,
  "listed_count": 3,
  "created_at": "Sat May 28 08:38:07 +0000 2016",
  "favourites_count": 40,
  "utc_offset": null,
  "time_zone": null,
  "geo_enabled": false,
  "verified": false,
  "statuses_count": 368,
  "lang": "en",
  "contributors_enabled": false,
  "is_translator": false,
  "is_translation_enabled": false,
  "profile_background_color": "000000",
  "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
  "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
  "profile_background_tile": false,
  "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/907526265627971584/T8gahYIg_normal.jpg",
  "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/907526265627971584/T8gahYIg_normal.jpg",
  "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/736476636015529987/1524287352",
  "profile_link_color": "9B0103",
  "profile_sidebar_border_color": "000000",
  "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "000000",
  "profile_text_color": "000000",
  "profile_use_background_image": false,
  "has_extended_profile": false,
  "default_profile": false,
  "default_profile_image": false,
  "following": false,
  "follow_request_sent": false,
  "notifications": false,
  "translator_type": "none"
}
```

What is causing this error I'm not sure.

How can I access properties of the object?

Comment: Can you fully expand the user object before you paste it in. It seems to be truncating some values off probably due to length.

Comment: @JakeG I have updated my question.

Comment: Can you confirm that the user logged in the OP was logged at the start of the render function?  In other words, the code should read `console.log(tweet) // this works?  console.log(tweet.user); // this works? console.log(tweet.user.profile_image_url); // come on, work!`

Comment: My guess would be those prior logs don't work either, that the user is being fetched asynchronously, and the render is being called too eagerly, before tweet.user is ready

Comment: @danh yeah.. `console.log(tweet)` works.. since I put api call thing on `componentDidMount()` hook

Comment: @Azima - please post that code, too.

Comment: can you console.log(tweet.user.profile_image_url) ?

Comment: @danh I have updated the post. I can access `tweet.user` but not `tweet.user.id` or any other properties.

Comment: @Azima - it's tough to understand because it's tough to see how you're conducting these experiments.  I can't tell what code logged the tweet.user, or what sort of logger was used.  Can you `console.log(JSON.stringify(tweet.user))` at the start of the render function and paste the log output?

Comment: @danh, I have posted the `tweet.user` output. Please check.

Comment: @Azima - can you confirm that was logged at the start of the render function?  The posted code doesn't say that at the moment.  Please update the code to show the logging.

Comment: @danh, yes.. updated.

Comment: @Azima - Thanks.  Now it's saying something rather remarkable:  at the top of the method, you can access tweet.user (and all of it's properties because the log statement can).  On the next lines -- in the JSX that you've now removed from your question for some reason -- that same object generates an error that says tweet.user is undefined.  Your logging statement looks like a typo. console.log(console.log...)  Is this code actually running to produce the output?  It's important to have these details correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181238/discussion-between-danh-and-azima).

Comment: @danh yes.. sorry that was a typo. .but it is producing the same output..
also, I cannot access any other properties of `tweet.user`. say trying to access `tweet.user.id` at the top of the method gives me the same `undefined id` message

Answer (score 1):

You can use `object.item`, notice in example one its within an array, so you would specify the first array with `obj[0]` then use `obj[0].item` dot notation.

For me to give you exactly what you are looking for, you would need to copy the full JSON object from start of the brackets `{ }`. or start and end of array `[]`. This one isn't valid, assuming you didn't copy the full thing. You can use a JSON beautifier to view the tree easier.

If your object has "item" you use `obj.item` (dot notation) else use `obj["item"]`. **Notice the quotation marks.**

```js
var obj = [
      {
      "one": "1",
      "two": "2",
      "nested": {
         "nested-one": "nested-1"
      }
    }]
    var obj2 = {
      "example_two": "example-2"
    }
    
var yours = {
  item: {
     name: "example"
  }
}
    console.log(obj[0].one)
    console.log(obj2.example_two)
    
    // Your case
    console.log(yours['item'].name)
```

So you take those priceables in your JSON object and then use `{obj.entry['item']}`